# Text to date format in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can i convert the table containing date in text format DY Mon DD YYYY into DD MM YY date format which can be used for sorting when exported to a spread sheet.

The first date format is "Sun Jan 6 2013" which needs to be converted to "06-Jan-13" to be in date format not text which can be sorted on spread sheet and the type of the column is Text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide an example of your first date format `DY Mon DD YYYY`

Comment: what is type of this column?

Comment: the first date format is "Sun Jan 6 2013" which needs to be converted to "06-Jan-13" to be in date format not text which can be sorted on spread sheet and the type of the column is Text.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the text you have to a `DATE` value, and then re-format it:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(date_column, 'DY MON DD YYYY'), 'DD MM YY')
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: Just to clarify i was using this earlier, however the output was in text format which didn't enable me to sort date on excel.

Comment: @user3139623 In Excel, just format it as date with this format and you should be good to go.